# Stop UIViewController Animation on dismiss

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController that I display full screen, then when the user touches a button I present another view controller like so:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:loadSaveViewController animated:YES];
```

I like the animation that happens when I transition ***TO*** the view controller i.e. the main view shifts down and slides off to the left and the new view controller is displayed with the nav bar at the top.

HOWEVER, when I go back using the button at the top of the nav bar the screen does the opposite.  The main screen appears, but with a nav bar at the top for a short time then the main screen shifts up.

How do I stop the main screen from doing the animation?  When the user returns to the main screen, I do not want them to see the nav bar and the shift up, I just want the main screen to appear, or slide in.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7, there are new classes that will allow you to control every aspect of animation. This website is very useful  [ios 7 transitioning](http://www.appdesignvault.com/custom-transition-ios-7/)

Comment: Yes, that is very interesting, but unfortunately, I need iOS6 support also and I did not see how to use the example with pushViewController so I get the default nag bar with a back button